# How to insert records and same time subtract balance fields records and update back to database use classic ASP

Tags: sql, ms-access, asp-classic

I'm new of ASP, May I know how to insert records and same time subtract balance fields records and update back to database ?

below my code, I tried but failed

```
<%
    set conn=server.createobject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.provider="Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    conn.open "C:\database\user.mdb"

    usrid = request.querystring("ID")
    outqty = request.querystring("outqty")
    balance1 = request.querystring("balance")
    stockcode = request.querystring("stockcode")

    sql = "insert into balance (stockcode,outqty,balance) values"
    sql = sql & "('" & request.form("stockcode") & "',"
    sql = sql & "'" & request.form("outqty") & "',"
    sql = sql & "'" & request.form("balance") & "')"


    sql2 = "update balance1 set "
    sql2 = sql2 & "balance1='" & request.form("balance1") & "'-"
    sql2 = sql2 & "outqty='" & request.form("outqty") & "'" 
    sql2 = sql2 & " where ID=" & usrid & "'"  

    on error resume next
    conn.Execute sql , recaffected
    conn.Execute sql2, recaffected

    if err <> 0 then
    response.write("No update perform")
    else
    response.write("<h3>" & recaffected & " record added</h3>")
    end if

    conn.close
    %>
```

anyone help is much appreciated.

Comment: Failed means what? Got any errors? Try printing out (response.write) both the SQL statements and see if they are correct

Comment: Flakes, no error, for insert statement no issued, only not able to update.

Comment: Don't save calculated balances to tables, calculate when needed. Review http://allenbrowne.com/AppInventory.html

Comment: Would not recommend `On Error Resume Next` as the name suggests if there is an error it reports it to the `Err` object and then skips to the next line of code. This is useful for error trapping but when debugging issues like "not able to update" you're best commenting it out to identify if there are underlying errors.